# Auto Layout causes infinite layoutSubviews loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, infinite-loop, layoutsubviews

I'm really puzzled by this, when I use auto layout on a subview the layoutSubview method loops infinitely.

All I'm doing is:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        _imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self addSubview:_imageView];

        [self applyConstraints];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)applyConstraints
{
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_imageView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_imageView)]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[_imageView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_imageView)]];
}
```

And this causes an infinite loop in layoutSubviews. Actually even when applyConstraints is not called the loop occurs, the only way to stop it from happening is setting 'translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints' to YES.

Has anyone encountered/solved this problem before?

**Update**
Just to clarify, this is an UIView subclass, which is used within a view controller. The view itself does not use auto layout, instead it's frame is set the old fashioned way after initialization.

Comment: Somewhere else you are doing wrong I guess, because I have copy pasted  your code and commented `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, still it is working fine, layoutSubview is not getting called infinitely.

Comment: I've worked around it using frames for now, when I get around to it  I'll try reproduce this in an empty project, I'll update the question when I do.

Meanwhile, do you know what could cause the infinite loop? I can't really seem to find anything on the subject of an infinite layoutSubviews loop anywhere.

Comment: You were right, it was caused somewhere else. One of the superviews removed & re-added the subviews within it's layoutSubviews method. I'm not sure why, as it's absolutely unnecessary...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The loop was caused by one of the superviews, which was removing its subviews, setting their (possibly new) frame and then re-adding them. As the piece of code was absolutely unnecessary I removed it which fixed the problem.

Comment: Good that you figured out the problem. :)

Comment: Indeed, Changing frame is not a probleme, but creating new UIVIEW and adding them to viewcontrollers view make didLayoutSubviews being call again.
And your right, this piece of code is unnecessary, no need to remove and recreate, juste reuse.

Answer (score 19):

This might help you.

layoutSubviews will be called

- When frame of the view changes
- When a view removed from the superview then it will be called on superview
- In UIScrollview, during scrolling.
- While adding the view to superView.
- During orientation change.

Answer (score 1):

This also turns up If there is an ambiguity, like two undetermined larger/less than equations. You are supposed to change  one of these constraints to direct equality. Also Try to detect this ambiguity by tracing.